# adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not updating UI across classes

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an app that utilizes a TSL 1128 reader to read RFID tags. It uses the IASCIICommandResponder Library to communicate with the reader.

I have one Class called orderFullfill.java that is responsible for the Listview and updating the UI for this class. Th

The Reader functionality is set up in another class (orderResponder.java) that implements this IASCIICommandResponder, so that it can run in the background whilst orderFullfill shows the changes made to the ArrayList.

I have tried passing the Arrayadapter from orderFullfill.java to orderResponder to call notifyDataSetChanged(); but that has no effect. I have to call addPigNumber() method on a button click to update my listview.

Ideally I need the listview to update when a new tag is added to the list. Please can someone help me apply notifyDataSetChanged() in the right place so that when I can a tag it will add to the list automatically. **I am very grateful for any help that is received.**

```
    public class orderFullfill extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener  {int where; public static ArrayList scannedPigs = new ArrayList<String>();
// The Reader currently in use
private Reader mReader = null;
private boolean mIsSelectingReader = false;
// The model that performs actions with the reader
private TriggerModel mModel;
public static String dispatchweek;
public static String customer;
public static String accountnumber;
public static String supplyfarm;
public static String breed;
public static int numberofpigs;
public static int pigNum;
public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public static String weekNow;
public static Context mContext;
Switch trick; TextView nameholder;
/**
 * @return the current AsciiCommander
 */
protected AsciiCommander getCommander()
{
    return AsciiCommander.sharedInstance();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.orderfullfill);
    mContext = orderFullfill.this;
    addPigNumber();
    InventoryCommand iCommand = InventoryCommand.synchronousCommand();
    iCommand.setFilterStrongest(TriState.YES);//high power reading
    trick = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.scanM2);
    trick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    trick.setChecked(true);
    trick.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.lowPowerScan));
    trick.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            InventoryCommand iCommand = new InventoryCommand();
            //InventoryCommand iCommand = InventoryCommand.synchronousCommand();
            if(isChecked)
            {
                iCommand.setTakeNoAction(TriState.YES);
                iCommand.setFilterStrongest(TriState.YES);// low power reading
                getCommander().executeCommand(iCommand);
                trick.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.lowPowerScan));
            }
            if(!isChecked)
            {
                trick.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.highPowerScan));
                iCommand.setFilterStrongest(TriState.NO);//high power reading
                iCommand.setTakeNoAction(TriState.NO);
                getCommander().executeCommand(iCommand);
            }

        }
    });
    nameholder = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameView);
    nameholder.setText(customer);
    AsciiCommander.createSharedInstance(getApplicationContext());

    final AsciiCommander commander = getCommander();

    // Ensure that all existing responders are removed
    commander.clearResponders();

    // Add the LoggerResponder - this simply echoes all lines received from the reader to the log
    // and passes the line onto the next responder
    // This is ADDED FIRST so that no other responder can consume received lines before they are logged.
    // commander.addResponder(new LoggerResponder());// logcat input
    // Add responder to enable the synchronous commands
  //  commander.addSynchronousResponder();
    commander.addResponder(new orderResponder());

    // Configure the ReaderManager when necessary
    ReaderManager.create(getApplicationContext());

    // Add observers for changes
    ReaderManager.sharedInstance().getReaderList().readerAddedEvent().addObserver(mAddedObserver);
    ReaderManager.sharedInstance().getReaderList().readerUpdatedEvent().addObserver(mUpdatedObserver);
    ReaderManager.sharedInstance().getReaderList().readerRemovedEvent().addObserver(mRemovedObserver);

    // Create a (custom) model and configure its commander and handler
    mModel = new TriggerModel();
    mModel.setCommander(getCommander());
    mModel.initialise();

    ListView scroller = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewD);
    scroller.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(orderFullfill.this, view);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(orderFullfill.this);
            popup.inflate(R.menu.edit_menu);
            where = position;
            popup.show();
        }
    });

     weekNow = orderResponder.getWeeknow();
}


   public ArrayAdapter getAdapter()
   {
       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scannedPigs);
       return adapter;
   }

public void addPigNumber()
{
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scannedPigs);
    TextView counter = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
     if(numberofpigs >= 0 )
    {
        counter.setText("Pigs Left: " +numberofpigs);
        if(numberofpigs == 0)
        {
            counter.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BCBDF3E8"));
        }
    }

    ListView scroller = findViewById(R.id.listviewD);
    try {
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        scroller.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        String result ="";
        result.equals(e.toString());
    }
}

public void orderdetailsOnclick(View view) {
    addPigNumber();
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Customer Order: " + customer);
    alert.setMessage("Account Number: " + accountnumber + "\r\n" +
                     "Dispatch Week: " + dispatchweek + "\r\n" +
                     "Supply Farm: " + supplyfarm + "\r\n" +
                     "Breed: "+ breed + "\r\n" + "Number of Pigs: " + pigNum);
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    alert.show();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    addPigNumber();

    // Register to receive notifications from the AsciiCommander
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(AsciiCommander.STATE_CHANGED_NOTIFICATION));

    // Remember if the pause/resume was caused by ReaderManager - this will be cleared when ReaderManager.onResume() is called
    boolean readerManagerDidCauseOnPause = ReaderManager.sharedInstance().didCauseOnPause();

    // The ReaderManager needs to know about Activity lifecycle changes
    ReaderManager.sharedInstance().onResume();

    // The Activity may start with a reader already connected (perhaps by another App)
    // Update the ReaderList which will add any unknown reader, firing events appropriately
    ReaderManager.sharedInstance().updateList();

    // Locate a Reader to use when necessary
    AutoSelectReader(!readerManagerDidCauseOnPause);

    mIsSelectingReader = false;

    displayReaderState();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Register to receive notifications from the AsciiCommander
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    addPigNumber();
    ReaderManager.sharedInstance().onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    // Remove observers for changes
    ReaderManager.sharedInstance().getReaderList().readerAddedEvent().removeObserver(mAddedObserver);
    ReaderManager.sharedInstance().getReaderList().readerUpdatedEvent().removeObserver(mUpdatedObserver);
    ReaderManager.sharedInstance().getReaderList().readerRemovedEvent().removeObserver(mRemovedObserver);
   // readResponder.tempList = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reader_menu, menu);
    // Reset, connect, disconnect dropdown menu
    mResetMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.reset_reader_menu_item);
    mConnectMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.connect_reader_menu_item);
    mDisconnectMenuItem= menu.findItem(R.id.disconnect_reader_menu_item);

    return true;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ReaderList Observers
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Observable.Observer<Reader> mAddedObserver = new Observable.Observer<Reader>()
{
    @Override
    public void update(Observable<? extends Reader> observable, Reader reader)
    {
        // See if this newly added Reader should be used
        AutoSelectReader(true);
    }
};

Observable.Observer<Reader> mUpdatedObserver = new Observable.Observer<Reader>()
{
    @Override
    public void update(Observable<? extends Reader> observable, Reader reader)
    {
    }
};

Observable.Observer<Reader> mRemovedObserver = new Observable.Observer<Reader>()
{
    @Override
    public void update(Observable<? extends Reader> observable, Reader reader)
    {
        // Was the current Reader removed
        if( reader == mReader)
        {
            mReader = null;

            // Stop using the old Reader
            getCommander().setReader(mReader);
        }
    }
};



@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.delete_menu:
            boolean complete = false;
            scannedPigs.remove(where);
            numberofpigs = numberofpigs + 1;
            //myDB.deleteEntry(scannedItems); -> IF YOU ADD IT TO THE DB REMOVE IT
            //select items from the list
            addPigNumber();
            return true;

        case R.id.edit_menu_:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

orderfullfill.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listviewD"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listviewD"
    android:layout_width="354dp"
    android:layout_height="221dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scanM2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/invoiceMaker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/makeInvoice"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scanM2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameView"
    android:layout_width="333dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="303dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scanM2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/orderdetailsBtn"
    android:layout_width="119dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:onClick="orderdetailsOnclick"
    android:text="@string/showOrder"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.887"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editTextNumber"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/scanM2"
    android:layout_width="359dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/listviewD"
    android:layout_marginTop="232dp"
    android:text="@string/highPowerScan"
    android:textOff="No"
    android:textOn="Yes"
    android:textSize="27dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.461"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderdetailsBtn" />/android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

orderResponder.java -> this is the class that the TSL reader communicates with via ASCII when reading RFID tags. The method Splicer adds the RFID values to the ArrayAdapter then notifyDataSetChanged(); is called. However nothing happens when this method is called from outside orderFullfill.class.

```
    public class orderResponder extends Application implements IAsciiCommandResponder {

public static boolean tempList;
NoteHelper myDB;

public List<String> getReadInput() {
    return readInput;
}

public void setReadInput(List<String> readInput) {
    this.readInput = readInput;
}

public static List<String> readInput = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public boolean isResponseFinished() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void clearLastResponse() {

}

@Override
public boolean processReceivedLine(String s, boolean b) throws Exception {
    isitMe(s);
    return false;
}
public List<String> getList()
{
    return readInput;
}

public boolean isitMe (String input)
{
    String firstFourChars = "";
    //get first 4 chars to see if it contains "EP: "
    if(input.length()>4)
    {
        firstFourChars = input.substring(0,4);
    }
    else
    {
        firstFourChars = input;
    }
    if(firstFourChars.equals("EP: "))// this is the inital identifier for the RFID tags
    {
        splicer(input);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


//takes the last 24 characters removing the 'EP: '
public void splicer (String input)
{ // ArrayAdapter magic = orderFullfill.getAdapter(); THIS Didnt work
    orderFullfill.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(orderFullfill.mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, orderFullfill.scannedPigs);
    String output ="";
    output = input.substring(input.length() -24);//maybe take 24 chars
        if (orderFullfill.scannedPigs.size() == 0) {
          //  orderFullfill.scannedPigs.add(output);

            orderFullfill.adapter.add(output);
            orderFullfill.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            orderFullfill.numberofpigs = orderFullfill.numberofpigs - 1;

        } else//if the list has values check you are not duplicating the values
        {
            if (orderFullfill.scannedPigs.contains(output)) {
                return;//you are already in the list
            } else//you are unique you can join the list
            {
               // orderFullfill.scannedPigs.add(output);
                orderFullfill.adapter.add(output);
                orderFullfill.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                orderFullfill.numberofpigs = orderFullfill.numberofpigs - 1;

            }
        }
}


public static String getWeeknow()
{
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String dateH = formatter.format(date);
    //String dateH = date.toString();
    String[] array = dateH.split("\\/");
    String output ="";
    int month = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    month = month -1;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(array[2]),month,Integer.parseInt(array[0]));
    int weekOfyear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    output = String.valueOf(weekOfyear);
    return output;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

create orderResponder constructor method. and send your activity(orderFullfill.this) and context to orderResponder as parameter. call like this;

```
((orderFullfill)activity).adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ((orderFullfill)activity).scannedPigs);

((orderFullfill)activity).adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

i hope it works.

Comment: I have a method that can be called from orderResponder call getAdapter()                   public static ArrayAdapter getAdapter()
       {
           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, scannedPigs);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           return adapter;
       }            This method passes the adapter across to orderResponder with the application context but it does not update the Listview when additonal details are added. How would you suggest I create a constructor to take in the parameters you suggest ?

Comment: I cant seem to instatiate the application now, E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.uk.tsl.rfid.samples.trigger, PID: 28913
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.uk.tsl.rfid.samples.trigger.orderResponder: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.uk.tsl.rfid.samples.trigger.orderResponder> has no zero argument constructor

Comment: getApplicationContext() only gets the context not the Activity itself. Could this possibly be the reason why it won't complie sucessfully ?

Comment: Define private context in orderFullfill and access with ((orderFullfill)activity).context. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the same error  :/ I wonder if there is a way to call addPigNumber() from orderResponder once Splicer() sucessfully adds a value to the adapter? Instead of using the orderResponder Constructor ?

Comment: Can you access context in that line without constructor? -> orderFullfill.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(orderFullfill.mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, orderFullfill.scannedPigs);    If you can access, you can access activity eather.

Comment: Yes I  can access the mContext and the Arraylist. it just doesn't notify orderFullfill that the data set has been changed.

Comment: Ok. you can access activity eather. Set private activity in orderFullfill and call like your context and try access like this; ((orderFullfill)activity).adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: It still has the same effect. It allows the orderResponder to read the tags and add it to the adapter. but Without calling .setAdapter(adapter); to the Listview in orderFullfill it is not taking any effect .